# How do I fix baseline alignment of bullet-items in beamerposter?

Tags: itemize, beamerposter

In `beamerposter`, 2008/03/11. v.1.07. (the version in Tex Live 2011), `itemize` bullets are misaligned:

```
\documentclass[final]{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[orientation=portrait,size=a4,scale=1.0,debug]{beamerposter}  % e.g. custom size poster
\begin{document}
 \begin{frame}{} 
  \begin{block}{\Large{Summary}}
   \begin{itemize}
    \item Item 1
    \item Item 2
    \item Item 3
   \end{itemize}
  \end{block}
 \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: illustration of misaligned itemize bullets]

- How can I fix the vertical alignment?

Comment: Remember that `\Large` is *not* a command receiving arguments: `\begin{block}{{\Large Summary}}` would be the "correct" way, but since the title is probably typeset in a box of its own, `\begin{block}{\Large Summary}` should suffice.

Comment: Right, thanks. This was a copy-paste from years old code :)

Comment: I made a note because that syntax might bite you, some day. Good to know that you know. `:)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in older versions of `beamerposter`. With newer versions, at least v1.12, available not in Tex Live 2011 but at http://www-i6.informatik.rwth-aachen.de/~dreuw/latexbeamerposter.php, this bug is fixed:

[image: Illustration of beamer itemize in newest version]

If you don't use the newest version, or you still want to tweak the vertical alignment, try something like this in your preamble:

```
\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}{\raisebox{0.1ex}{$\blacktriangleright$}\hskip0.1em}
```

Replace `\blacktriangleright` by the symbol you want to use for your `itemize` (see [the LaTeX comprehensive symbol list](http://math.uoregon.edu/resources/compsymb.pdf) for a complete list.

However, I don't know how to fix it when using more complicated bullets such as ball (that I think is drawn with `tikz`).

Answer (score 1):

For Tikz drawn bullets you can use the baseline option. For example:

```
\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}{\tikz[baseline={([yshift=-.7ex]
  current bounding box.center)}]{\draw[color=Color1,fill=Color1, semithick]
    circle(0.2);}}
```